# Html5 amp story convert to mo4 video

Tags: html, css

What is best practice to convert html5 and css3 animation or amp-stories to mp4 video?

Is there any library which can do this out of the box?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618048/best-way-to-create-video-from-html5-animation

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is utilize Chrome's Tab Capture API.

https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture

Basically, you build a browser extension and create a media stream and Media Recorder.  Something like this:

```
const mediaStream = chrome.tabCapture.captureOffscreenTab('https://example.com', {
  audio: true,
  video: true,
  videoConstraints: {
    width: 1280,
    height: 960
  }
});
```

Then, use [MediaRecorder](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/mediarecorder) to capture the output and save it, in the same way you would any other MediaStream.

Comment: @DejanMilosevic Yes, hence `audio: true`.

Comment: And how would I target specific start moment and specific end moment? For example begining and end of amp-story?

Comment: You can use postMessage to send data between the extension and your page.  https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/messaging  That way, you can tell it when to start/stop recording.